# Turn Off SpellCheck With Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I'm fairly new to javascript, I'm decent when it comes to Visual Basic & C#. I'm trying to create a complete replica of Inspect Element on iOS using the shortcuts app.
First, I created a shortcut, and made it so it'll receive the safari web page and run the javascript code below.

```js
    document.body.contentEditable = "true"; 
    document.designMode = "on";
    completion();
```

which completely allows you to edit the page, but it'll show put the red dots indicator for words you spelt wrongs. I don't know if this is possible but is there a code I can implement which will turn this feature off.

[image: example]

I've tried

```js
    document.body.contentEditable = "true"; 
    document.designMode = "on"; 
    spellcheck = "false"
    completion():
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable it, I think it has to be for a specified element, like so:

```js
document.body.contentEditable = "true";
document.body.designMode = "on";
document.body.spellcheck = false
```

```html
<body>
  Spell something rong
</body>
```

[MDN Docs for `spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck#browser_compatibility)